# clearInterval not working electron js How to resolve this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

clearInterval not working in this code. How to resolve this?

```
    var inter;
    ipcMain.on("start-stop",(err,data)=>{
    console.log(data.data)
   
    function start(){
        inter = setInterval(function (){handlegole();}, minsNum * 60 * 1000);
    }
    function stop(){
        clearInterval(inter);
    }
    if(data.data == 'Stop'){
        stop();
    } else if(data.data == 'Start'){
        start();
    }
```

Comment: please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's possible that `start` is getting called again before `stop` is, which results in a new interval starting and the old one never being cleared (because `inter` no longer holds the corresponding identifier) - but really that's just guesswork. We need to see this code in its actual context.

Comment: Can you give a small example of opening and closing intervals with a single button? Thank u.

Comment: You override on every "start-stop" event `inter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime Electron's IPC `start-stop` channel is called, `inter` is declared...

```js
var inter;
```

but because initialisations are not hoisted (in this case, within the `ipcMain.on()` function scope)...

```js
function start(){
    inter = setInterval(function (){handlegole();}, minsNum * 60 * 1000);
}
```

the value of `inter` is **`undefined`** when referenced in the `stop` function...

```js
function stop(){
    clearInterval(inter);
}
```

To clearly define your code, stop using `var` where possible.

Scope your variables or functions with `let` and `const` (inside the desired function or block level scope).

I have reproduced a simple working example of what I believe you are trying to achieve.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

let minsNum = 0.008333; // 0.5 second interval
let inter; // Declare outside 'electronIpcMain.on()' function scope so `stop()` function can reference it

electronIpcMain.on('start-stop', (event, controlValue) => {
    function start() {
        console.log('Start..!'); // Testing
        inter = setInterval(function() {handleGoal();}, minsNum * 60 * 1000);
        console.log(inter); // Testing
    }

    function stop() {
        console.log('Stop..!');  // Testing
        clearInterval(inter);
        console.log(inter); // Testing
    }

    (controlValue === 'Start') ? start() : stop();
})

function handleGoal() {
    console.log('handleGoal'); // Testing
}
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From render to main
        startStop: (controlValue) => {
            ipcRenderer.send('start-stop', controlValue);
        }
    }
);
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <label for="control">Control: </label>
        <input type="button" id="control" value="Start">
    </body>

    <script>
        let control = document.getElementById('control');

        control.addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRenderer.startStop(control.value);
            control.value = (control.value === 'Start') ? 'Stop' : 'Start';
        })
    </script>
</html>
```